# How to send a notification for a specific token, flutter, firebase messaging and node.js

Tags: node.js, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am designing an application and in it I will have a notification system between clients after an onCreate event.
Here is my index.js code

```
    const functions= require("firebase-functions");
    const admin =require("firebase-admin");
    admin.initializeApp(); 
    var fcm = admin.messaging();
    
    // Node.js e.g via a Firebase Cloud Function
    exports.sendPush = functions.firestore.document('notifications/{notificationId}').onCreate((change, context)=>{
    const chauffeur = change.after.data().chauffeur;
    const date_reception = change.after.data().date_reception;
    const send_name = change.after.data().send_name;
    const token = change.after.data().token;

    console.log('chauffeur' + chauffeur);
    console.log('date_reception' + date_reception);
    console.log('send_name' + send_name);
    console.log('token' + token);

    const payload = {
       notification:{
            title: 'New message',
            body: 'Message reçu de' + chauffeur,
            sound: "default",
        },
        data:{
            'chauffeur':chauffeur,
            'date_reception': date_reception,
            'send_name': send_name,
        },
    }
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);
});
```

et mon code dart&flutter

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    Future<void> _messageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
      print('background message ${message.notification!.body}');
    }
    
    void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_messageHandler);
      runApp(MessagingTutorial());
    }
    
    class MessagingTutorial extends StatelessWidget {
      static const String idScreen = "note";
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Firebase Messaging',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'Firebase Messaging'),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      MyHomePage({Key? key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
    
      final String? title;
    
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      late FirebaseMessaging messaging;
      String? notificationText;
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
        messaging.getToken().then((value) {
          print(value);
        });
        FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage event) {
          RemoteNotification? notification = event.notification;
          AndroidNotification? androidNotification = event.notification!.android;
          print("message recieved");
          print(event.notification!.body);
          print(event.data.values);
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text("Notification ${event.data['title']}"),
                  content: Text(event.notification!.body!),
                  actions: [
                    Row(children: [
                      TextButton(
                        child: Text("Annuler"),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        child: Text("Ok"),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                      )
                    ])
                  ],
                );
              });
        });
        FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
          print('Message clicked!');
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title!),
          ),
          body: Center(child: Text("Messaging Tutorial")),
        );
      }
    }
```

The problem is, when I save in my "notifications" collection, the notification doesn't show even in the background, not even in forground.

After saving in the collection, the number of uses of the function increases but no effect in the application.
[usage for the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khfu6.png)
When I send the test message from firebase cloud messaging, everything is working fine

[Cloud messaging test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T81wn.png)
I don't know how to fix this, if anyone can help me i would be very happy.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There could be a lot of points that fail here. The cold start could cause that you don't wait enought for the notification. When your App is open it won't show anything if you havend written code for it to handle messages while in focus. You could have an outdated notification token. Do you update it on your database?

Can you try it with this shema of the `payload` to:

```
const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: "title",
        body: "body",
      },
      webpush: {
        notification: {
          title: "title",
          body: "body",
        },
      },
      data: {
        test: 'test',
      },
    }
```